# Use Mailchimp templates for Magento transactional emails

Tags: email-templates, transactional-mail

I am about to set up marketing automation and abandoned cart emails using Mailchimps integration for Magento. I would however like to align the design between the marketing emails from Mailchimp and the transactional emails in Magento. What is the easiest way to use a template from Mailchimp for Magento's transactional emails?